# Container Usage: Top level selector used outside scoped containers in activities

Tags: bots, rpa, uipath

I am developing a bot in UIPath. While Analysing my File it shows an error like,

```
Error   UI-DBP-006       Container Usage           Top level selector used outside scoped containers in activities Element Exist TypeInto Click
Recommendation
Using scopes such as Open Browser and Application gives a level of reusability in selectors. Try to use scopes instead of direct UI Activities. 
[Learn more.](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/lang-en/docs/ui-dbp-006)
```

I couldn't understand this as I am using different selectors for the 3 activities. Could anyone please help

Answer (score 0):

This happened because I have placed the main application selector element

For Eg:

> <app=‘facebook.exe’ ctrlname=‘mainpage’ />

in the selector of the Click button selector like

> <app=‘facebook.exe’ ctrlname=‘mainpage’ />
> <button=‘submit’ />

Due to this, an issue occurred for me.
What you have to do is to **replace the Click button selector like**

> <button=‘submit’ />

alone.
This will resolve your issue.

Thanks